# default value for <select> tag is setting in chrome and edge but not in IE

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am setting two values 2018 and My Name on the created method to two separate data properties.
I am passing the data property as v-bind to a component.

My problem is, in chrome and edge both the values are being set to two dropdowns ( tag) as default value on page load. but in IE 11 only the year value is being set on page load not my name value.

Does anyone know why is that ?

App.vue

```
data: function() {
  return {
    selectedYear: null,
    selectedFacility: null,
  }
},
created: function() {
  //this line will return 2018
  this.selectedYear = this.tableData.year.replace(/\D/g, "");
  //this return will return "My Name"
  this.selectedFacility = this.tableData.tableInfo.rows[0].sName;
}

<template>
  <filter-page v-bind:years="years" v-bind:sel-year="selectedYear"
  v-bind:available-facility="tableData" v-bind:sel- 
   facility="selectedFacility"></filter-page>
 </template>
```

in filterPage.vue

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" style="width:120px" id="select-Year" v-model="selYear">
<option v-for="yr in years" v-bind:value="yr" >{{ yr }}</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control input-sm" id="select-facility" v-model="selFacility">
 <option v-for="fieldRows in availableFacility.tableInfo.rows">
       {{fieldRows.facilityName}}
 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: please show the code

Comment: i have edited my question @brk. this works perfectly with chrome and edge. but only the year value is setting in IE 11

Comment: UPDATE: i acheived this by including a span tag inside the options tag. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I acheived this by including a span tag inside the options tag. thanks.